# JavaScript create an object outside of a constructor function and add 2 methods

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

I have a constructor function `Example` that has 2 methods.

I want to create a new object outside of the constructor function and call the 2 methods that are in it.

How do I do that, the task doesn't say anything about the rest of the content.

Something like `var newEx = new Example` will create an object identical to the constructor function.

Thank you

```
function Example (){
    this.name = Mike;
    this.surname = Ryan;
    this.age = 50;
    this.x = function(){
        return 20
    }
    this.y = function (){
        return 50
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Example` does *not* "create an object identical to the constructor function". It creates a new object and uses the constructor function to initialize it.

Comment: _"...create an object ... and **add** 2 methods"_ vs. _"...create an object ... and **call** the 2 methods that are in it"_ ?

Comment: On the face of it, the answer is: `var ex = new Example(); ex.x(); ex.y();` (perhaps outputting the results they return). But...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Simple Example For You** 
I think it will help you to understand.

```
function Person(name,dob){
    this.name = name;
    this.birthday = new Date(dob);
    this.calAge = function(){
        const diff = Date.now() - this.birthday.getTime();
        const ageDate = new Date(diff);
        return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970 );
    }
}

const shovon = new Person('Shovon', '8-26-1991');
console.log(shovon);
console.log(shovon.name);
console.log(shovon.calAge());
```

**NOW, FROM YOUR CODE**

```
function Example(){
    this.name = Mike;
    this.surname = Ryan;
    this.age = 50;
    this.x = function(){
        return 20
    }
    this.y = function (){
        return 50
    }
}

const newObj = new Example(); // New Object Created
newObj.x(); // call x function , it will execute and return 20
console.log(newObj.x()); // Now it will show the result in console

//You can store the return value in a variable like this 
var a = newObj.x();
```

Comment: if it helps you to understand, please accept the answer, so that new people will get help, thanks